MotherBoard or NVME disc error - unclear
Recently there was a power outage, and while the PC seemed fine, woke up later to all NVME disks not being bootable.
I had a dual boot win11 and ubuntu, I was still able to access all the files on the disks (including efi partition) after booting from a ubuntu disk on key.
I am using Z590 UD AC Gigabyte Mother Board, have 2 samsgong evo and 1 GigaByte nvme.
I tried every trick in the book - could not reinstall any OS on any the NVME's (was using two of them, leaving the windows one out in hope I could repair it without formatting).
After alot of effort, and what seemed mostly random , I was able to install Windows and Ubuntu on two sata drives, the process was not clean and required alot of manual work.
I do not have any additional NVME's or MB's, so not sure how to diagnoise thise further. Would be happy for any suggestions.
Right now it looks like MB issue to me, as its all 3 nvmes and the other disks are not working very well, but I am not sure.
